# How do I make a line graph from a dataframe in bokeh?

Tags: python, graph, line, bokeh

I'm reading a .csv file in bokeh which has two columns: one for date and one for the values corresponding to that date. I'm trying to make a line graph with the dates on the x axis and the values on y, but it isn't working. Any ideas?

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

output_file('output.html')

df = pd.read_csv('speedgraphak29.csv')
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x=df.dates, y=df.windspeed, line_width=2)


show(p)
```

It's returning an empty graph. What should I do?

Comment: Have you inspected `df` to make sure it actually contains what you expect? Shouldn't you be telling pandas to interpret the `dates` column as datetime values? Are there any errors in the JS console? What *exactly* does "empty graph" mean? (better: add a screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide an example of the input data I had to make something up. You probably forgot to specify that the dates column should be interpreted as datetime values as bigreddot noted. Here is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

output_file('output.html')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'dates': ["1-1-2019", "2-1-2019", "3-1-2019", "4-1-2019", "5-1-2019", "6-1-2019", "7-1-2019", "8-1-2019", "9-1-2019", "10-1-2019"], 'windspeed': [10, 15, 20,30 , 25, 5, 15, 30, 35, 25]})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x='dates', y='windspeed', line_width=2, source=source)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this. Say you have a CSV called `sample_data.csv` with columns `Date` and `Amount`. Just to add on to what Jasper had.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource



output_file('output.html')

df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x='Date', y='Amount', line_width=2, source=source)

show(p)
```

*In this case, read the CSV with the column as a date format*. Using `ColumnDataSource` allows you to use advanced features like hovering over a plot to see more details if needed.
You may alternatively also use lists directly which would look like.

```
p.line(x='my_list_of_dates', y='my_list_of_counts', line_width=2)
```

This would mean reading each column and making a list from it. All in all, using [ColumnDataSource](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#columndatasource) would allow you to directly call a column by its name.